# Please help me check my metric definition of isolated point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, terminology

I translated the word definitions into the more symbolic form below, but as they aren't mere negations of each other, it was a little tricky. Is there any mistake below (especially for 'isolated point')?

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space.
>
> A point $x\in M$ is called an **accumulation point** of $A$ if for
>   each $\epsilon>0$, there is some $z\in A$ such that $d(x,z)<\epsilon$
>   and $z\neq x$.
>
> A point $x\in A \subset M$ is called an **isolated point** of $A$ if
>   there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $z\in A\backslash\{x\}, d(x,z)>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Looks good.

Another formulation would be:

A point $x\in A$ is called an *isolated point of A* if there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap A=\{x\}.$

Or:

$x\in A$ is called an *isolated point of $A$* if $\{x\}$ is open in the subspace $(A,d)$.

Comment: Thanks. Is your first (set-notational) definition more useful, or the metric one I gave more commonly used?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ss}{\smallsetminus}$The definitions are fine, but they are not the negation of each other. However they are closely related.

Note that $z\neq x$ and $d(x,z)<\epsilon$ means that $z\in B(x,\epsilon)\ss\{x\}=\hat B(x,\epsilon)$, so $A\cap\hat B(x,\epsilon)\neq \varnothing$.

Thus we can say $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ $$\hat B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\neq \varnothing$$

Now suppose $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A$. This means that there exists a ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ such that $$\hat B(x,\epsilon)\cap A=\varnothing$$

$(1)$ If $x\in A$ we would call $x$ an isolated point of $A$.

$(2)$ If $x\notin A$ we would call $x$ a point in the *exterior* of $A$, meaning $x$ is an *interior* point  of $X\ss A$.

Comment: To expand on what you said: iso$(A)=A\backslash ($acc$(A) \cap A)$, where iso(A) and acc(A) respectively denote the set of isolated and accumulation points of a set A.  Again, is this correct? (I figured it out myself.)

Comment: Another question is as I asked in the other answer: which is more useful in proofs: the set-notational definition you gave, or the metric one I wrote? Thanks.